# Generating a number based on post ID

Tags: php, formatting

I am trying to generate a number that will be 5 digits including the post ID. For example: if post ID is 25, the number will be 00025.

So far my codes are below. It's working but is there any better way to lessen the code line? more dynamic?

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$postidlength = strlen($post_id);
if($postidlength = 1){
    $zero="0000";
}

elseif($postidlength = 2){
    $zero="000";
}
elseif($postidlength = 3){
    $zero="00";
}
elseif($postidlength = 4){
    $zero="0";
}
else{
    echo "invalid id";
} 


$result = $zero.$post_id;
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) is the function you're looking for.

```
echo str_pad( get_the_ID(), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't think about it.